# Game Center Real Time Match Tutorial (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, real-time, game-center

I have taught myself coding over the past several months and have created my own game to near completion. The next step for my game is to integrate a real-time multiplayer match (1 v 1) and I have no idea where to start. I have searched all of the internet for a tutorial or code examples of something similar.

If someone could point me in the direction of a example code or a tutorial for real time games, and in swift I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like there's a new way to do it in iOS 10, as the Game Center app is going away. http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/06/20/inside-ios-10-with-game-center-app-gone-invites-are-managed-by-messages Here's a video from WWDC 2016 covering changes to Game Center. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/611/

Comment: Maybe start with Apple's Game Center Programming Guide https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html